# Properly set up ESlint and Prettier with Nuxt3

Tags: vuejs3, eslint, prettier, nuxtjs3

I'm new to Vue3 and Nuxt3 and I'm starting a new project from scratch, trying to set it up properly with Typescript.

This is how my `package.json` looks like

```json
{
    "name": "nuxt-prototype",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "build": "nuxt build",
        "dev": "nuxt dev",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@privatePackage/commitlint-config": "^1.0.1",
        "@privatePackage/prettier-config": "^2.0.0",
        "@cspell/dict-de-de": "^3.1.0",
        "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
        "@nuxtjs/color-mode": "^3.3.0",
        "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^12.0.0",
        "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^4.1.0",
        "@nuxtjs/stylelint-module": "^5.1.0",
        "@types/node": "^20.4.8",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.2.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.2.1",
        "@vueuse/core": "^10.3.0",
        "@vueuse/nuxt": "^10.3.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "cspell": "^6.31.2",
        "eslint": "^8.46.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "9.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^10.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.16.1",
        "lint-staged": "^13.2.3",
        "nuxt": "^3.6.5",
        "postcss": "^8.4.27",
        "postcss-html": "^1.5.0",
        "prettier": "3.0.1",
        "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.4.1",
        "stylelint": "^15.10.2",
        "stylelint-config-standard-scss": "^10.0.0",
        "stylelint-config-standard-vue": "^1.0.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "sass": "^1.64.2",
        "simple-git-hooks": "^2.9.0",
        "typescript": "^5.1.6"
    },
    "lint-staged": {
        "*.{html,js,json,jsx,md,scss,ts,tsx,vue}": "cspell --no-must-find-files",
        "*.{html,js,json,jsx,scss,ts,tsx,vue}": "prettier --check",
        "*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}": "eslint",
        "*.{scss,vue}": "stylelint"
    },
    "simple-git-hooks": {
        "commit-msg": "npx commitlint --edit \"$1\"",
        "pre-commit": "npx lint-staged"
    },
    "prettier": "@privatePackage/prettier-config"
}
```

Then `eslintrc.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    extends: [
        "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript",
        "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended",
        "prettier",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    ],
    parser: "vue-eslint-parser",
    parserOptions: {
        parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser"
    },
    plugins: ["simple-import-sort"],
    root: true,
    env: {
        browser: true,
        node: true
    },
    // Lint .*.js files in the project root directory.
    ignorePatterns: ["!/.*.js", "types/generated.d.ts"],
    // TODO: check the clashes with "index" routing in nuxt.
    rules: {
        "vue/multi-word-component-names": 0
    }
};
```

Finally, my `prettier.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: ["prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"]
};
```

I have also added the following to `nuxt.config.ts`

```
    modules: [
        "@nuxtjs/color-mode",
        "@nuxtjs/eslint-module",
        "@nuxtjs/stylelint-module",
        "@vueuse/nuxt"
    ]
```

Any suggestions on how to improve this? The reason I am sure this is not working correctly is because I was trying to add `vueIndentScriptAndStyle` to ESlint and Prettier.

ESlint would correctly detect that scripts and styles need to be indented, however prettier would not take this into consideration when formatting.

Any advice on how to better set this up is more than welcomed.

Comment: This tutorial might be helpful
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54yr53NOcdc&t=91s

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@nuxtjs/eslint-config` and `@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript` haven't been updated in almost a year at the time of writing. I would recommend switching to [`@antfu/eslint-config`](https://github.com/antfu/eslint-config). It's created by Anthony Fu, a core team member of Vue, Nuxt and Vite. It's very sane and is updated frequently. Using that, you can also remove `eslint-plugin-vue`, as it's included in that config.

You don't need `eslint-plugin-prettier` when you have `eslint-config-prettier`.
As for `vueIndentScriptAndStyle`, that's a setting for Prettier and has nothing to do with ESLint. As long as you have `prettier` as the last item in `extends`, in your ESLint config, any ESLint rules that conflict with Prettier should be turned off.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would help you but this is my configurations on my projects and so far, I don't see any issue with it.

[Nuxt Eslit](https://github.com/nuxt/eslint-config#nuxtjseslint-config-and-nuxtjseslint-config-typescript)

`npm i -D @nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript`

`npm i eslint`

In the root folder there is a

`.eslintrc`

```js
{
    "extends": [
        "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "no-console": "warn",
        "indent": "off",
        "vue/html-indent": "off",
        "vue/html-self-closing": "off",
        "space-before-function-paren": "off",
        "space-in-parens": "off",
        "no-lonely-if": "off",
        "import/no-unresolved": "off",
        "import/no-default-export": "off",
        "import/default": "off",
        "import/no-named-as-default-member": "off",
        "func-call-spacing": "off",
        "vue/first-attribute-linebreak ": "off",
        "vue/html-closing-bracket-newline": "off",
        "vue/multi-word-component-names": "off",
        "vue/no-v-html": "off",
        "vue/first-attribute-linebreak": "off"
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I've also added the package that you mention, as you can see above. But the Typescript one (nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript)